# Implementing Random-Forest or Lasso with a spatio-temporal shapefile in R?

Tags: r, random-forest, shapefile, lasso-regression, variable-selection

Is there a way to implement either a **Random-Forest** or **Lasso model** (for variable selection) in R with a pooled spatio-temporal dataset?

**Data:** My data is a pooled spatial dataset for multiple years. Specifically, it is a polygon with information of properties and when they were sold (I only have one sale per house).

**Goal:** My goal is to run either a Random Forest or Lasso regression so I can see which variables are important to explain my model.

**Issues:** I have found some resources but they either:

a) Work with data frames that are not spatio-temporal datasets ([example 1](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-science-tutorials-training-a-random-forest-in-r-a883cc1bacd1), [example 2](https://www.css.cornell.edu/faculty/dgr2/_static/files/R_html/CompareRandomForestPackages.html#3_Random_forest_with_ranger), [example 3](https://statmath.wu.ac.at/%7Ehornik/DTM/Presentations/pres_ranger.pdf))

b) Work with spatio-temporal data sets that are raster. And my dataset is a shapefile. Not a raster (such as the [CAST package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CAST/vignettes/cast01-CAST-intro.html), [GeoMLA](https://github.com/thengl/GeoMLA), [example 4](https://www.css.cornell.edu/faculty/dgr2/_static/files/R_html/exMeuseTreesForests.html#9_Spatial_random_forests), [example 5](https://peerj.com/articles/5518/), [example 6](https://blogs.fu-berlin.de/reseda/rf-classification/), [example 7](https://rpubs.com/SoldevilaJorge/985338), [example 8](https://blogs.ubc.ca/tdeenik/2021/07/22/random-forest-modelling-in-r-step-by-step-process/))

I also tried with the [spatialRF package](https://blasbenito.github.io/spatialRF/), however it is not clear for me how I should define both the distance matrix and the distance threshold matrix.

Any guide would be really appreciated it!